# Get utf-8 instead of \u escaped sequence with Swagger and Connexion in Python

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, swagger, connexion

I'm trying to use Swagger to build an API using Python and Connexion. I want to generate **UTF-8 encoded JSON** output but I get a **\u** escaped sequence like this in my responses:

```
euro \u20ac
```

instead of this:

```
euro €
```

I'm already specifying the charset for the endpoint, maybe I'm missing other Swagger setting in the specification regarding marshalling:

```
produces:
- "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

and the response header is correctly returning the content type:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I also tried to add this to the generated "`swagger_server/__main__.py`" with same results:

```
app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.app.json_encoder.ensure_ascii = False
app.app.json_encoder.encoding="utf-8"
```

Edit: Here's my *requirements.txt*. The one generated by SwaggerEditor doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6.9, it requires *connexion == 1.1.15* but it fails with *ImportError: cannot import name 'FileStorage'*. It would be great for somebody to give a correct one. By now I just need *Connexion* and its dependencies:

```
connexion == 2.4.0
python_dateutil == 2.6.0
setuptools >= 21.0.0
```

How can I achieve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Is there an attribute to set to avoid generating the `\u` stuff?

Comment: could you share your requirements.txt ?

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, I have updated the question with the requirements.txt . It would be really great for you to paste one that works. Thanks anyway, regards